# Issues loading a file in R

Tags: r

I cannot successfully load the data contained in the Qld+20-34+Age+Groups.zip file which can be found at...

https://github.com/SuperSi2217/datasample

I've opened the file in a txt editor and deleted the unwanted header and tail rows. I've tried various `read_csv` and `read.csv` combinations to import it, but it always pulls in an extra column at the end of the data set which is populated with `NA`s. I've tried converting it to a text file and using `read_delim` and `read.table`, and still get the same issues.

```
df <- read_delim("C:/Qld 20-34 Age Groups Clean.txt", col_names = FALSE, quote = "\"", na = c("", "NA"), delim = ",")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_character(),
  X2 = col_character(),
  X3 = col_integer(),
  X4 = col_integer(),
  X5 = col_integer(),
  X6 = col_integer(),
  X7 = col_character()
)
Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row 
# A tibble: 1 x 5 
col       row   col  expected    actual expected     
<int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr> 
actual 1 1423530  <NA> 7 columns 6 columns file 
# ... with 1 more variables: file <chr>

df <- read_delim("C:/Qld 20-34 Age Groups Clean.txt", delim = ",", col_names = FALSE, quote = "\"", na = c("", "NA"))
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_character(),
  X2 = col_character(),
  X3 = col_integer(),
  X4 = col_integer(),
  X5 = col_integer(),
  X6 = col_integer(),
  X7 = col_character()
)
|========================================================| 100%   29 MB

df <- read_csv("C:/qldtest.csv", col_names = TRUE)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_character(),
  X2 = col_character(),
  X6 = col_integer()
)
```

The above imports the data but with an extra column. When I try to work on it, it does weird things - see below. To get it down to the three columns I need I use...

```
df <- df %>% 
       select(X1, X2, X6)
```

Ultimately I need the data to look something like...

```
X1    | X2 | X6
----------|----------------|------
Abbotsbury|4032,QLD        |0
na        |4033,QLD        |0
na        |4034,QLD        |10
na        |4035,QLD        |0
Smith Town|4032,QLD        |0
na        |4033,QLD        |220
na        |4034,QLD        |0
na        |4035,QLD        |0
```

I then run...

```
transform(df, X1 = na.locf(Suburb))
```

...to fill down the last know value in the first column so it becomes...

```
X1    | X2 | X6
----------|----------------|------
Abbotsbury|4032,QLD        |0
Abbotsbury|4033,QLD        |0
Abbotsbury|4034,QLD        |10
Abbotsbury|4035,QLD        |0
Smith Town|4032,QLD        |0
Smith Town|4033,QLD        |220
Smith Town|4034,QLD        |0
Smith Town|4035,QLD        |0
```

This works OK but with the following warning...

```
+ transform(df, X1 = na.locf(df))
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(object) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(object[1L]) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

That said, the data looks right.

However, when I run the following to select only those records where the X6 column is > 0, R visibly adds in another four columns, yet the variable count in the global environment still says 3??

```
df1 <- df %>%
        filter(X6 > 0)
```

...these look like

```
X1.X1.X1  |X1.X1.X2|X1.X1.X6|X1.X2   |X1.X6|X2      |X6
----------|--------|--------|--------|-----|--------|--
Abbotsbury|4613,QLD|3       |4613,QLD|3    |4613,QLD|3
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

The first few rows of the file look like the attached image.

[image: Capture]

[image: Capture1]

Comment: I think we absolutely need to see first few rows of this file.  Can you edit your question to clearly show this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I've added an screen grab of the file header.

Comment: Is your source file an Excel or other spreadsheet file?  You can't use `read.csv` on that.

Comment: The original source is a Microsoft Excel Comma Separated .csv file. I've opened this in a txt editor and converted it to text. I've tried loading the .csv and .txt versions. They both load all the records, but then I run into the issues described above. I've tried versions of read_csv, read_delim, read.csv and read.table - utilising different variables/criteria in each.

Comment: This is really just a cleanup job on the Excel side.  If you can't do that, forget about doing it in R.  The `read.csv` function expects fairly rigid structure.

Comment: I can't do it in Excel because there are 1,423,540 rows.

Comment: Then perhaps do it using an app language like Java, Perl, Python, etc.  If there are so many rows are you even sure that your question covered all th3 edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the file in a text editor like Sublime, you will see that there is a comma after every row:

[image: screenshot_csv]

This is why there is an extra column.

I would assume that you don't need the information above the data, so I would suggest to use `skip = 11` to read the data. Since there is a disclaimer below the data, you could use `n_max` to exclude it by limiting the number of rows read.

```
library(readr)
file <- "C:/Qld 20-34 Age Groups Clean.txt"
df <- read_delim(file, col_names = FALSE, quote = "\"", na = c("", "NA"), 
                 delim = ",", skip = 11, n_max = 1423540)
df$X7 <- NULL
head(df, n = 5)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     X1        X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
      <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Abbeywood 4000, QLD     0     0     0     0
2      <NA> 4005, QLD     0     0     0     0
3      <NA> 4006, QLD     0     0     0     0
4      <NA> 4007, QLD     0     0     0     0
5      <NA> 4008, QLD     0     0     0     0
```

In order to replace NAs with the most recent non-NAs, you can use

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(X1 = na.locf(df$X1))

head(df, n = 5)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
         X1        X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
      <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Abbeywood 4000, QLD     0     0     0     0
2      <NA> 4005, QLD     0     0     0     0
3      <NA> 4006, QLD     0     0     0     0
4      <NA> 4007, QLD     0     0     0     0
5      <NA> 4008, QLD     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I can get the data in, and looking like the tibble above. The problem comes when I run df <- transform(df, X1 = na.locf(df)). It adds the extra columns shown in the OP. The tibble in Clemens post turns into the attached screengrab - Capture1. If I just run transform(df, X1 = na.locf(df)) (without "df <-") I get "Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs". Not sure what is going on. CC: @drmariod.

Comment: You are passing the whole data.frame (tibble) to the function `na.locf()`. If you instead use `transform(df, X1 = na.locf(df$X1))` it will work. However, this is a very slow operation, so I would suggest to do something like: `df <- df %>% mutate(X1 = na.locf(df$X1))`

Comment: Doh! You nailed it 100%. Now it all works like a dream. I'm sure in a previous version I utilised na.locf in this way, but forgot! Anyway this works like a dream now. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about just skipping the first 9 rows and using the normal header of the file?

Something like this:

```
jnk <- 
  read.csv('~/Downloads/Qld 20-34 Age Groups.csv', skip=9, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You can have a look with

```
summary(jnk)
```

and for example use your `df %>% filter(X6 > 0)` command which would look like this

```
head(jnk %>% filter(Total > 0))
```

Or did I miss some important point in the question?